# How to join KStream and KTable without 'changelog topic'

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I joined KStream and KTable. Below is my code.

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KTable<String, String> addressTable = builder.table(ADDRESS_TABLE);
KStream<String, String> orderStream = builder.stream(ORDER_STREAM);
orderStream.join(addressTable, 
        (order, address) -> order + " send to " + address)
        .to(ORDER_JOIN_STREAM);

KafkaStreams streams;
streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
streams.start();
```

After executing this code, a new topic is created.

```
$ ./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list
__consumer_offsets
order-join-application3-address-store-name-changelog
address
order
```

How can I execute the code without '~~~~changlog' topic.

- broker version : 0.11.0.2
- stream version : 2.7.0

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want the topic?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I try to prevent the cluster from having more topics.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is possible since

> In the Kafka Streams DSL, an input stream of an aggregation operation
> can be a KStream or a KTable, but the output stream will always be a
> KTable.

extracted from [Kafka aggregations](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/concepts.html#aggregations) which also uses Streams DSL like in [Kafka join](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/concepts.html#joins). Basically what Kafka join is doing is executing a lookup of the KStream on the KTable that they call "changelog stream" from [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#kstream-ktable-join).

> KStream-KTable joins are always non-windowed joins. They allow you to
> perform table lookups against a KTable (changelog stream) upon
> receiving a new record from the KStream (record stream). An example
> use case would be to enrich a stream of user activities (KStream) with
> the latest user profile information (KTable).